# Pyinstaller giving error while converting .py to an .exe

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to convert a small programm from .py to .exe The program uses GUI and data collection from NSE website and is working fine in python environment..
its giving error as
ImportError: cannot import name 'Sequence' from 'collections' and many warnings.  What do I miss here?

I tried to find the file sequence.py and put it in the \lib folder and tried with -F and --clean --noconsole options as well....May be I missed something ?  Please guide...Thanks

Comment: I could solve this. 1. Upgrade Pyinstaller to latest version .  Now when I use pyinstaller, it gives error message related to Obsolete package pathlib...  2 So remove (delete) the pathlib package from the given location.  and it works...